# LDAP Groupfilter with range

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

i have the following Groupfilter:

```
(name=*)(member;range=0-1)
```

The reason i use "range" is that i have groups in AD > 1500 users.
With the above testfilter i try to find the first two users.

If I use this filter, the result is always 0, I tried different filter variants, unfortunately without success.

If i just use `(name=*)`, then i can find all the members.

Do someone have an idea, what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LDAP filter is not valid. When you have more than one condition, you need to add either an "and" (&) or "or" (|) operator.

But also, the "range" is not valid in the LDAP filter itself. It belongs in the list of attributes to return. How that's done exactly depends on which programming language you are using to make the query. If you show the rest of your code, I can help there.

Comment: Thanks your you help. We are using .net as programming language. We found a solution.